# Better design for a Call To Action button overlayed on a video

Tags: buttons, call-to-action, click

My company hosts marketing videos and we are in the middle of redesigning our Call to Actions that we overlay on top of the video to direct users to our client's booking site.

I currently have a reasonably large button centered in the bottom half of the video with a slight opacity that becomes opaque on hover, but I feel it looks a bit flat and doesn't invite people to click.

Before starting the video:
[image]

While playing:
[image]

Is there anything I can do to make the button stand out a bit more and encourage more clicks? The current colour selection is to match our logo but I'm happy to change it if another colour is more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like it is the **invasive** nature of the "Book Now" button that is making people avoid clicking it.

I can't tell how the whole website is designed but given that there is a close button, I feel like this is a modal/overlay.

This means that there would be a "Watch video" button on the main page. Have the "Book Now" button right next to it(it might already be there).

**In here**, only show the "Book Now" button when ***the video is about to end*** (in the last 5 seconds). This triggers the user to take an action and is less of an annoyance while the video is playing

Comment: This is the new design that isn't live yet. This particular page is in a modal which is invoked by clicking a thumbnail with a play button embedded in the customer's page. Whether or not a "Book Now" button is adjacent to the thumbnail would be up to the customer and not impacted by us.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, I'd recommend having the "Book Now" button *outside* the video player. Maybe below, like in YouTube where the Subscribe button goes. The idea is to not bother the user with a CTA

Comment: So I ended up only showing the button in the last 10 seconds of the video, giving it a bit of box shadow to make it stand out more and reducing the size of the button and text. It's a lot less in your face now and will hopefully encourage people to click once they are interested in the content. I'll accept your answer since it pushed me to reconsider how I was displaying it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Try an orange colour that fits your company's colour palette.**

It has a high contrast compared to the playback controls of your video.

Orange works well because it has yellow in it (red and yellow makes orange). Yellow is the first colour a human eye notices. Add that to the high contrast with the blue colours your already have and you'll have a great call-to-action button that stands out.

[image]